# WSO2 EI custom swagger in capp files

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I'm developing an API in wso2 ei 6.6 and I'm setting my own swagger. I would like to upload this API swagger definition API using a carbon app, but I realized that when using a capp file, the swagger API is always autogenerted and useless.

Is there a way to upload the custom API swagger definition using a carbon file?

Answer (score 0):

As of now, the integration studio does not have the capability to generate and store the swagger definitions. Therefore you will need to manually copy the swagger definition using the EI management console UI.